# accessing a folder from another folder

Tags: html, css

i am currently trying to make a working sign up/in page. The problem lies that i am fairly new to HTML and C# programming and i am wondering how do i access a home.HTML file in a diffrent folder so that when the "Sign up" button is pressed it goes to that home.HTML file. I have to folders. One which name is "Sign up page" and one which name is "Home Page" and i have my sign in/up thing in "Sign up page" but i don't know how so that when the button is pressed it goes to the other folder "Home Page" and opens "home.HTML" even tho in two diffrent folders. Is there any possible way for that? Here is the button that when pressed needs to go to home.html file

```
    <button type="button" class="signup-btn"><Strong>Sign up.</Strong></button>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use a form and submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the button add `<a> </a>` tag and link the html page. But I recommended you to not use anchor tag inside Button tag.

```
    <button type="button" class="signup-btn"><Strong><a href="../homepage/home.html">Sign up</a></Strong></button>
```

recommended:

```
<a href="../homepage/home.html" class="signup-btn">Sign up</a>
```

and style it by the class name

Comment: This is invalid HTML. Button elements are forbidden from containing links (and vice versa). Don't use a button.

Comment: This does almost the same as having the HREF in the button tag. Both things give me an error:

Cannot GET /homepage/home.html

Comment: you can use the absolute path rather than relative path... in href

Comment: No, DO NOT DO THIS. You should put the button INSIDE the `<a>` like this: `<a href='href'><button>Sign up</button></a>` and the text will bot be underlined.

Comment: @Ath.Bar. - Don't do that either. Buttons may not be inside links. Links may not be inside buttons.

Comment: then use `onclick="location.assign(location)"`

Answer (score -1):

You can use anchor tag like

```
<a href ="https://stackoverflow.com/">Sign up</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean?